# string of second textbox.text have to be same with first

Tags: string, textbox

there are two textboxes and for example user input to first textbox
"emre", when user input to second textbox "e", ok...
but the others, program will be error in messagebox.
My problem is that: if user input different character,
program explode :) I suppose my wrong is here : textbox2.text[i]==a[i]

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication2
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        string a;
        string final = "";
        int i = 0;
        string b;
        private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            a = textBox1.Text;
        }

        private void textBox2_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (textBox2.Text[i] == a[i])
            {

                final += textBox2.Text[i];
                textBox2.Text = final;
                i++;
            }
            else
            {
                textBox2.Text = final;
                MessageBox.Show("Lütfen aynı ismi girin!");

            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please tag with the correct programming language/platform

Comment: i can't understand what's ur problem

Comment: sorry for my bad eng.there are two textboxes.First textbox is main textbox.Second textbox accepts only same string from textbox1.text step by step (characters)

Comment: For example . ı enter the first : John      And I have to write only John to second textbox

Comment: if I write Johm it will give error : you have to write same names.

Comment: i said the answer.

Comment: can you say me what you want exactly ?

Comment: bro, there will be just two textbox, nothing else. You will enter a name to textbox1. Later, you can enter just same name to textbox2.

Comment: so if you enter different name to textbox 2, program wont allow you :)